# "more elements supplied than there are to replace" R error in for loop

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R, and this is my first question. I've searched and searched and searched and can't seem to find anything that helps.

I am scraping information from a website. I've gotten it to work on one page, but now I'm trying to automate the process so that it goes through all 26 pages. For some reason, when I try to execute the following code, I get this error message:

```
Error in imgPgVar[[d]] <- readHTMLTable((mybrowser$getPageSource()[[1]]),  : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

Here's the code:

```
numbers <- c(1:26)
imgPgVar <- paste0("p", seq_along(numbers))
for (d in 1:length(numbers)){
  mybrowser$navigate(paste0("https://secure.istockphoto.com/gb/file_downloads.php?id=20386766&PageSetting=&order=CreationDate&page=", d))
  imgPgVar[[d]] <-  readHTMLTable((mybrowser$getPageSource()[[1]]), header = TRUE)
  imgPgVar[[d]] <-  (imgPgVar[[d]])[[2]]
  d <- d+1
}
```

imgPgVar is a list I generated to use as variables: p1, p2, p3... It has 26 values.

I believe that to be all of the relevant information. If I can provide anything else, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try substituting the second line with `imgPgVar <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(numbers)); names(imgPgVar ) <- paste0("p", seq_along(numbers))`.